# How to hide a button if object has more than specific number of characters in Django?

Tags: django

For example:

`view`:

```
def hello(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html', {'words': 'I love Stackoverflow'})
```

`index`:

```
{% if words %}
    <a href="">Click here</a>
    {{ words }}
{% endif %}
```

I want to hide the link (`Click here`) whenever the words object has greater than specific number of characters (`length of 'I love Stackoverflow'`), let say 50. How would you go about doing that?

Comment: You're going to need to write a custom template filter for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
{% if words|length <= 50 %}
    <a href="">Click here</a>
{% endif %}
```

Above, `length` is a filter. Django has a lot more cool [built-in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference).

---

### Alternative approach

You can calculate the length of `words` in the view.

```
def hello(...):
    words = 'I love Stackoverflow'
    show_link = True if len(words) < 50 else False
    return render(... {'words': words, 'show_link': show_link})
```

Then in your template you can check if `show_link` is `True` based on which you'll show the link.

```
{% if show_link %}
    <a href="">Click here</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @Brandon See this example in docs -  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#filters

Comment: You're correct. In previous versions, the `length` filter returned a string, but they have updated it to return an int, so you can indeed use `length` to check for the condition.

Comment: @Bun Maybe you're using an older version, then. I am using version 1.6.7 and it works for me all right.

Comment: @Bun Anyways, I've edited my answer with an *alternative approach*.

Comment: thanks @xyres. I'm using django 1.8 with python 3.4. The object words in my project is html. Does it make any difference from regular string?

Comment: @Bun If `words` is something like `{'words': '<html>...</html>'}`, then I don't think it makes any difference because it's a string anyway. But do give it a try with a *regular string*.